# Differences between "inasmuch as" vs "as much as"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, compound-adjectives

Can anyone provide me with some examples illustrating the differences between mentioned adjectives. Is it possible to use them interchangeably on various occasions?

Comment: i couldn't find inasmuch as in the dictionary! looking forward to answers.

Comment: You mustn't have looked very hard. I found more than 1000 pages using Google. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inasmuch%20as)

Comment: Yeah you are right. :D

Comment: The occasions on which you are likely to need _inasmuch_ are rare. If you're not sure about it, it's best to avoid it.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Inasmuch as google supports your assertion, you'll find that some of these words perform a lot of heavy lifting in the legal community--not as technical terms of the art, but as efficient language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition of INASMUCH AS :

1: in the degree that ; insofar as
2: in view of the fact that ; since

Example: The economic forecast for the coming decade looks promising, inasmuch as we can predict that far in advance.

Synonyms: insofar as, insomuch as, insomuch that, so far as

Source : http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inasmuch%20as

Comment: So it's not possible to use them interchangeably?

Comment: Genuinely curious: how does this answer address the distinction between `inasmuch` and `as much as`?  Isn't that the question?  I think you've just defined `inasmuch`?

Answer (score 0):

in‧as‧much as
/ˌɪnəzˈmʌtʆ əz/ conjunction (formal)
used to explain the way in which what you are saying is true

Ex: Ann is guilty, inasmuch as she knew what the others were planning.

as much: an amount that is equal and not less
as much (...) as

Ex: I hope you have as much fun as I did.

there is another meaning to the first one: which is because or since. The latter does not have this meaning.

Ex: you can't have your share of the cake, inas much as (since,because) you didn't accompany us buying it.